# afnetworking post method working fine in objective-c but in swift is showing parameter missing

Tags: swift

afnetworking post method working fine in objective-c but in swift is showing parameter missing

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:"apiurl" )! as URL)
let session = URLSession.shared  request.httpMethod = "POST"

let params = ["appId":"1","deviceId":"1","deviceToken":"1"] as Dictionary<String, String>

request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Response: \(response)")})

task.resume()
```

Comment: if you are looking for a good networking framework for Swift, you shoud use Alamofire (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), or Moya (https://github.com/Moya/Moya)

Comment: What's the issue? You are not using AFNetworking, you are using (NS)URLSession, iOS framework. Also, what's the `response`? What's the value of `error`? You may need to set some headers (for content-type for instance).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one:

```
func HTTPsendRequest(request: NSMutableURLRequest,
                     callback: @escaping (String, String?) -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared
        .dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                callback("", error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                callback(NSString(data: data!,
                                  encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String, nil)
            }
    }

    task.resume()
}

func HTTPPostJSON(url: String,  data: NSData,
                  callback: @escaping (String, String?) -> Void) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url) as! URL)
    print("",request)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpBody = data as Data
    HTTPsendRequest(request: request, callback: callback)
}


/////how to use:


func example() {

    let url = "apiurl"
    let para:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    para.setValue("1", forKey: "appId")
    para.setValue("1", forKey: "deviceId")
    para.setValue("1", forKey: "deviceToken")
    print(para)
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: para, options: .prettyPrinted)
        // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data

        let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
        // here "decoded" is of type `Any`, decoded from JSON data

        // you can now cast it with the right type
        if decoded is [String:String] {
            // use dictFromJSON

            HTTPPostJSON(url: url, data:jsonData as NSData) { (response, error) -> Void in
                print(response);
                //here is the response
            }

        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```